# PL/SQL sql trigger for updating a view

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I have the player_value view which contains player id, player name and player second name from player table.
I have to make a trigger which update the player table if I modify the information from the view.

I get some warnings when I want to create my trigger. Can you help me?

```
DROP VIEW player_value;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW player_value AS
SELECT p.ID,p.name,p.sname,p.value
FROM player p;




DROP TRIGGER up_value;
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER up_value
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
ON player_value
BEGIN 

        update player
        set value=:new.value
        where ID=:new.ID;
    end if;
end;
/
```

Comment: "*get some warnings*" and the warnings are? What does `show error` give you?

Comment: Does oracle allow triggers on views>?

Comment: it looks like there's an end if without an if

Comment: @Mihai: yes, it does: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS20041

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra `END IF` statement. Also, you're missing `FOR EACH ROW`. My guess is that there used to be an `IF UPDATE` statement in there, e.g.:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER up_value
INSTEAD OF UPDATE ON player_value FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
    IF (UPDATING AND :new.value <> :old.value) THEN
        UPDATE player
           SET value = :new.value
         WHERE ID = :new.ID;
    END IF;
END;
/
```

But this can be more easily accomplished as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER up_value
INSTEAD OF UPDATE OF value ON player_value FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE player
       SET value = :new.value
     WHERE ID = :new.ID;
END;
/
```

Hope this helps.